# Map gps coordinates to given image with corresponding coordinate system

Tags: google-maps-api-3, gps

I have a map, which is accurate (enough) to the real world map, as viewed in google maps. 
I'm projecting the drawn image using the `google.maps.ImageMapType` class, thus the corners of the new, drawn, map are (sw)-90,-180 and (ne)90,180.
Now, knowing the coordinates of the south-west and north-east of the overlay in the real-world map, how do I convert GPS coordinates to this new scale?

Comment: The corners of your image are clearly **not** (sw)-90,-180 and (ne)90,180. I told you last week, when you asked the same question, that unless you're using a custom projection, **there's nothing to convert**.Have you tried placing a marker within the image, (for exanmple in Paris)?

Comment: Ok, here is the problem. I am using the drawn map as the entire map, by setting an imageMapType. This results in europe being projected as if it were the entire world ( with getBounds() showing the google maps maxima of -85.05~,85.05~,-180,180 ). Does this qualify as being it's own projection?

Comment: If that was the case, then your image would not fit on top of the normal image of Europe. Better show us your code of how you load the image.

Comment: If it won't work it is no use. You can choose to be stubborn and not accept what I'm saying but **unless you're using a custom projection there's nothing to convert**.

Comment: No, your question should be "why do my coordinates not match", and post working code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Fair enough. The current code is available and working, here: http://jsfiddle.net/leongersen/u6bdS/3/

Comment: Updated for readability: http://jsfiddle.net/leongersen/u6bdS/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I added a marker in "Paris" to [**your jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u6bdS/6/), but the marker is clearly not where it should be.

I think you might be mixing `google.maps.MapType` object and `google.maps.ImageMapType`

`google.maps.ImageMapType` uses a `google.maps.ImageMapTypeOptions` object, which should have a `getTileUrl()` method, but instead you have a `getTile()` method which is breaking the projection.

Comment: There is indeed a difference between the two, and I managed to figure it out. Thanks for your help!